why does LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT increase the version even without saving data
So I have the example code for withdrawing money from target bank account and I tried to prevent the race condition using optimistic lock. I knew that this type of issue is more suitable with pessimistic lock or exclusive lock however I'm just trying to experiment with the optimistic lock. the code may look like this.
@Data
@Entity
public class BankAccount {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private BigDecimal balance;
    @Version
    private Long version;
}

interface BankAccountRepository extends JpaRepository<BankAccount, Long> {
    @Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)
    Optional<BankAccount> findFirstWithLockById(Long id)
}

@Service
@RequiredAllArgsConstructor
public class BankAccountService {
    public final BankAccountRepository bankAccountRepository;    
    
    @Transactional
    public void withdrawn(Long accountId, BigDecimal amount) {
        BankAccount bankAccount = bankAccountRepository.findFirstWithLockById(id)
                                                       .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException());
        if (amount > 0 && amount < bankAccount.getBalance()) {
            bankAccount.setBalance(bankAccount.getBalance() - amount);
            bankAccountRepository.save(bankAccount);
        }
        // or else do nothing
    }
}

So let's say starting from bank account with version 1. What I expected is that, if the record got updated successfully it should change its version from 1 to 2 however it changed to 3 instead. What I have found so far is that, whenever findFirstWithLockById got executed it increase the version by 1 so it changed from 1 to 2 and then when it saved to the database it increased the version again from 2 to 3 like so
current version = 1
bankAccountRepository.findFirstWithLockById current version = 2
bankAccountRepository.save version = 3

so even there's no update at all but the method findFirstWithLockById with optimistic lock still increase the version in the database. Why is that ? or this is how it supposed to work.

That's basically how OPTISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT is supposed to work: "In addition, calling a lock of type LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT on a versioned object, will also force an update (increment) to the entity's version column."

It does exactly what its documentation and its name implies: it forces an increment, always. It's unclear to me what you're asking here (other than that we read the documentation and repeat it to you).
